# D3.js and C# Communication and Rendering Speeds

Tags: c#, javascript, d3.js, cefsharp

I'm working on an application using [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) to wrap the [CEF Project](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) to allow use of C#. I'm gathering data on the C# side and shooting the data off to JavaScript to manipulate into visual displays.  I'm using [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) to turn the data into line graphs.  There are about 15 graphs that get updated on an individual basis.  I am testing the refresh rates/rendering of the line charts by use of the following function in C#:

```
public void RunTest1()
{
    //Fake data for UI testing
    //=====================================================
    int x = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    while (x < 50)
    {
        int y = 0;
        while (y < this.sensors.Length)
        {
            //Generate random reading between 30-40
            float num = random.Next(30, 41);

            //Add the number to the next sensor
            this.sensors[y].addReading(num);  
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    //=====================================================

    this.TestCompleted();
}
```

Every time new data gets added to the `sensor` array, an event in the UI thread is fired off.  That event starts a new thread, and sends the message to JavaScript.  The following is the code that is fired when the event is fired off:

```
private void newDataRead(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Grab the id from the propertyname
    string functionName = e.PropertyName;
    string sensorID;
    if (functionName.Length < 14) //ID is last character
    {
        sensorID = functionName.Substring(12, 1);
    }
    else //ID is last two characters
    {
        sensorID = functionName.Substring(12, 2);
    }

    //Grab the correct dataset
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(sensorID);
    float[] dataSet = test.sensors[x].readingsToArray();
    string script = String.Format(
        "window['addData']({0},{1});" +
        "window['updateSensor']({0}, {2});",
        x, dataSet[dataSet.Length - 1], test.mode);

    ExecuteJavaScript(script);
}

private void ExecuteJavaScript(string script)
{
    Thread executeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => webView.ExecuteScript(script)));
    executeThread.Start();
}
```

On the JavaScript side, everything is cool if I run the outer test loop for 10 iterations or less, but once I start getting above 10, I see noticeable slow downs, and anything over 50 starts to get pretty laggy.  This is how I am handling updating the graphs with D3.js on the JavaScript side:

```
//Called from C#
function addData(index, value) {
    dataSet[index].push(value);
}

//Called from C#
function updateSensor(index, test) {
    switch (test) {
        case 0:
            updateSensorTest1(index);
            break;
        case 1:
            updateSensorTest2(index);
            break;
        case 2:
            updateSensorTest3(index);
            break;
    }
}

//Called from JavaScript
function updateSensorTest1(index) {
    var width = $('#t1-graph-' + index).width();
    var height = $('#t1-graph-' + index).height();

    if (index == 15) {
        loop_count++;
        $('#t1-loop-count').text(loop_count);
    }

    var svg = d3.select('#t1-svg-' + index);

    //Define domain and range of dataSet
    x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, dataSet[index].length])
        .range([0 + padding, width - padding]);

    //Define lines
    line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
        .y(function(d) { return -1 * y(d); });

    //Path the lines
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .attr("d", line(dataSet[index]));

    //Update avg-temp
    var sum = 0;
    var end = dataSet[index].length;
    for (var i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        sum += dataSet[index][i];
    }
    $('#t1-avg-temp-' + index).text('Avg Temp: ' + (parseFloat((sum / i).toFixed(2))));
}
```

`dataSet` is an array, structured like so:

```
var dataSet = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]];
```

Is there anything I can do on the JavaScript side of things to make this render/refresh any faster?  At some points after a hundred, it just bogs down and it does like 50 frames worth of updates in one refresh...

Thanks in advance for any help!